# how to read variables from CMakeLists.txt to cpp file

Tags: c++, cmake

```
if (WITH_TEST)
    add_subdirectory(test/unitTesting)
endif(WITH_TEST)
```

How do you read the `with_test` variable in a `.cpp` file?

Comment: [add_definitions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_definitions.html)

Comment: [target_compile_definitions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_compile_definitions.html) is better

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to add preprocessor definition.

in your CMakeLists :

```
add_definitions(-DWITH_TEST_VALUE ="${WITH_TEST}")
```

And in you source code you could do something like this :

```
#ifdef WITH_TEST_VALUE
constexpr auto WITH_TEST = WITH_TEST_VALUE;
#else
 // something 
#endif
```

Comment: cmake  -DWITH_TEST=ON ../   when it compiles it gives error i.e c++: error: =ON: No such file or directory